# Why do I keep getting emails from accounts I have deleted?

Tags: support, newsletter

I deleted a number of stack accounts, for example for the Ethereum stack exchange amongst others, yet I keep getting weekly emails from them. Why? And how can I stop this, especially since the account has been deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are still subscribed to the newsletter for the site. You need to go into your profile settings and unsubscribe from any you no longer wish to receive.

Direct link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/newsletters/current